# How to submit a text area field in react using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have this form:

```
 <form
   onSubmit={addDescriptions}
   style={{
     display: 'flex',
     justifyContent: 'flex-start',
     alignItems: 'center',
   }}
 >
    <Textarea
      {...bindValue}
      onKeyPress={handleUserKeyPress}
      placeholder="Here is a sample placeholder"
      size="sm"
      isFullWidth="true"
    />
 </form>
```

And here is the function that should trigger the onSubmit function of the form. How do I trigger that function exactly?

```
const handleUserKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && !e.shiftKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Here I want to trigger the forms onSubmit funciton
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form
   onSubmit={handleUserKeyPress}
   style={{
     display: 'flex',
     justifyContent: 'flex-start',
     alignItems: 'center',
   }}
 >
    <Textarea
      {...bindValue}
      onKeyPress={handleUserKeyPress}
      placeholder="Here is a sample placeholder"
      size="sm"
      isFullWidth="true"
    />
 </form>


const handleUserKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && !e.shiftKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
      addDescriptions()//onSubmit funciton
    }
 };
```

Comment: Ahhh hahaa then I'm a moron, thanks ;)
But why do I need the form element then after all? Would it work without it? Is this the standard way to do forms with text area?

Comment: you're not a moron! keep learning you are on the right track. and I using form is because it has onSumbit which is triggered by an action in one of the elements within the form and it also has meaning unlike div